# How can i beautify a string into Python using Typescript Angular?

Tags: python, angular, typescript

I'm trying to beautify a string into Python to show it in HTML page.

I'm receiving the string from a database and it's not formatted, but it's only on one line like this:

```
for count in range(2):  global expression; expression = 'happy'; stop();
```

I want to show it indented and formatted in Python language.

```
for count in range(2):
    global expression
    expression = "happy"
    stop()
```

Is there a method or a Rest API to solve this problem in Angular Typescript?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add whitspace characters in the string

```
public data = "for count in range(2):  \t\n global expression; \t\n expression = 'happy'; \t\n stop();"
```

Html File:

```
<p class="response-title">{{data}}</p>
```

css

```
.response-title {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: I was searching for a method to do this because I need to beautify several strings dynamically.